# Call function in a seperate div tagad from href link

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have two files: *index.php* and *cart.php*

In *cart.php* I have few three functions - `products_all()`, `products_shirts()`, `products_hoodies()`. Those functions get info from my database and outputs it if called.

I want each of those functions to be called by clicking on hyperlinks and then to be outputed in a `div` tag, so that only the `div` tag is being refreshed not the whole site.

I read about jQuery/AJAX function load, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: it's all about ajax, this is questions site, we don't make scripting here, add your code to see if we can help. show us what you have done until now, and we will try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the whole page to be refreshed, there is no way around using ajax.

But it's not that hard. When using a library like jQuery, you can do it in a few lines.

Your HTNL + javscript code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
function callFunction(yourfunction)
{
    $.post('cart.php', { "function": yourfunction }, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#functionOne").on("click", function()
    {
        callFunction(1)
    });

    $("#functionTwo").on("click", function()
    {
        callFunction(2)
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="functionOne">function one</a>
    <a id="functionTwo">function two</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And on the server side (cart.php) something like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['function']))
{
    switch ($_POST['function'])
    {
        case 1:
            functionOne();
            break;
        case 2:
            functionTwo();
            break;
    }
}

function functionOne()
{
    echo "hi, i am func1";
}

function functionTwo()
{
    echo "hi, i am func2";
}
```

This should get you started!